# Add values from a second column depending upon values via a dropdown in the first

Tags: google-sheets

I have a dropdown with several options. If the value is "OK", I'm trying to grab the number that's in the corresponding column.

So if the word "OK" is chosen from any dropdown in column A, the corresponding value in column B will get added to one cell.

```
 A      B  
ok      4
no      1
ok      6
```

Here is the SUM formula I'm using, but it's clearly not working:

```
=SUMHOURS(SUMIF(A3:A300,{“Ok”},B3:B300))
```

So the total in the single cell that has the formula would be `10`. My spreadsheet has hundreds of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
=sumif(A:A,"OK",B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have {} in your formula.

Change this

```
=SUMHOURS(SUMIF(A3:A300,{“Ok”},B3:B300))
```

to this

```
=sumif(A3:A300,"OK",B3:B300)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very odd. I tried both formulas but still couldn't render the drop down. Tried this:

```
 =SUM(FILTER(B3:B,A3:A="OK"))
```

and that worked!